# option selected not working from AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selected

I'm new to AngularJS, so it could be really simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out. The problem is not in the AngularJS code itself, but I'm sure it is somehow connected, because I've tried it in a blank pure-HTML test page, and it worked, how it's supposed to.

*headers.html:*

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            Sort headers by:
            <select ng-model="sortHeaders">
                <option value="rating">Rating</option>
                <option value="id" selected>ID</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="header in headers | filter:search | orderBy:sortHeaders">
        <td>{{header.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{header.title}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem here is, as the title says, with `<option value="id" selected>` not being selected at page load, how it's supposed to be.
*headers.html* is, obviously, a template for data output. And it does the job perfectly, except for this `selected` problem.

It's loaded from *headers_app.js:*

```
var headersApp = angular.module('headersApp', []);

headersApp.directive('headers', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/headers.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.headers = data.headers;
        });
    },
    templateUrl: '/templates/headers.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('linked headersApp');
    }
};
}]);
```

and, of course, there is this guy inside *index.html:*

```
...
<headers>
</headers>
...
```

Once again, everything else works as expected. The only problem is that supposed-to-be-selected option is not actually selected at page load.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.sortHeaders  = "id";
    }
```

As said in other responses, you can do it this way also:

```
<select ng-model="sortHeaders">
    <option value="rating">Rating</option>
    <option value="id" ng-selected="true">ID</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it does it. But still. Any idea why it is not working with "selected" attribute?

Comment: Can you check out the DOM see if `selected` it still is there? Angular might thrown that away because he will select the option that is equals to the model in the select

Comment: thanks, even though I solved it a bit differently in the end, I think your answer is the best solution for the way I wrote it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at angularjs docs. You can use the [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) for this.

**Example in docs:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<label>Check me to select: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected"></label>
<br/>
<select aria-label="ngSelected demo">
  <option>Hello!</option>
  <option id="greet" ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Paulo, though links are useful, it is preferred to answer in such a way that the reader doesn't have to follow a link.  Would you please edit your answer to contain a summary or the essential points from the link?

Comment: Hi, Ivan! Thanks for you suggestion. Next time I'll take care with my answers. I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use expression in ng-selected

```
<OPTION ng-selected="expression">
  ...
</OPTION>

<select ng-model="selectedid">
<option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione...</option>
   <option ng-repeat="item in list" 
   ng-selected="{{item.Value}} === {{selectedid}}" 
   value="{{item.Value}}">{{item.Text}}  
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you should use the ngSelected directive instead of selected, like so:

```
<select ng-model="sortHeaders">
    <option value="rating">Rating</option>
    <option value="id" ng-selected="selected">ID</option>
</select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: doesn't work for some reason. same result as with `selected`

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by adding to *headers.app*

```
$scope.sortBy = ['id','rating'];
```

and replacing my `<select>` block with

```
<select ng-model="sortHeaders">
<option ng-repeat="option in sortBy"
    value="{{option}}"
    ng-selected="{{option=='id'}}">{{option | uppercase}}</option>
</select>
```

I didn't use `ng-options` bacause in my case it's a 1-d array of values and using of `ng-options` is not, in this case, the needed, nor the most elegant (as it seems to me), solution.

And thank you guys for the links to `ng-selected`, found them really useful.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<option  ng-selected="true">Select Event Name</option>
```

as your default